# Is there a way to programmatically configure target rules filters in NLog 4.6?

Tags: c#, nlog

I am trying to wrap all of my NLog configurations into a C# class that can be utilized as a part of my company's "common" library, but I need to be able to support logger filtering. I am specifically trying to implement thresholds to ignore repeated messages (think DDOS). I have been able to port all of my settings from the NLog.config file except for these filtering settings.

The below is the example code from NLog on how to configure filtering in the .config file, but I have not been able to find any way to replicate this in the exposed class methods.

```xml
<logger name="*" writeTo="file">
  <filters defaultAction='Log'>
    <when condition="length('${message}') > 100" action="Ignore" />
  </filters>
</logger>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `Filter` collection under a `LoggingRule`.

You could translate to this:

```
var config = LogManager.Configuration;

// some target
var fileTarget = new FileTarget();

// set-up rule with filter
var loggingRule = new LoggingRule("*", fileTarget);
loggingRule.DefaultFilterResult = FilterResult.Log;
loggingRule.Filters.Add(new ConditionBasedFilter()
{
    Condition = "length('${message}') > 100",
    Action = FilterResult.Ignore
});

config.LoggingRules.Add(loggingRule);

// apply config
LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

Comment: Also added here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages